# How to make Neo4j Traversal faster?

Tags: java, neo4j, bigdata

I am assigning a temp property for all my relationships, but it is taking a lot of time with around 1,900 relationships. I just want to get a better performance by doing this.

```
    TraversalDescription tempTraversal  = this.database.traversalDescription()
    .depthFirst()
    .uniqueness(Uniqueness.RELATIONSHIP_GLOBAL);
    String uuidString = "flw-"+uuid.toString();
    Transaction tx = database.beginTx();
    try {
        for(Relationship r : tempTraversal.traverse(this.nSource)
            .relationships()){
            if (r.hasProperty("weight"))
                r.setProperty(uuidString,r.getProperty("weight"));
        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("assingTempProperty: " + e);
        tx.failure();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }
```

is any better solution out there?

Comment: how big is your graph in total? you don't specify any directons or rel-types? did you actually count the # of rels returned from the traverser? What do you originally wanted to do?

Comment: I just want to set a property for all the relationships in Graph with a temp value. Have 1900 relationships, 400 nodes. Also I've count the rels and traverser is doing well. This is a pre-processing for a MaxFlow Algorithm.

Comment: This should be instant. Something is really wrong. What does "a lot of time" mean?

Comment: If you just want to set the property on all relationships you can use GlobalGraphOperations.at(database).getAllRelationships()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I looked into it and learned something.

If you have a sparsely connected graph, and apply relationship-uniqueness, you have to explore very very long paths to really find all the unique relationships in your graph, so you have to meander back and forth until you find the last globally unique relationship.

You kind up explore the whole graph along a single path.

For putting that into number, I generated a graph of 400 nodes with 10% of the nodes connected.

You end up with a maximum path length of: 15845, exploring 1 288 374 paths.

Here is the code I used:

```
@Test
public void testTraversal() throws Exception {
    GraphDatabaseService db = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    int count=0;
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        for (int i=0;i<400;i++) {
            nodes.add(db.createNode());
        }
        DynamicRelationshipType knows = DynamicRelationshipType.withName("KNOWS");
        for (Node node1 : nodes) {
            for (Node node2 : nodes) {
                double random = Math.random();
                if (random < 0.1 && node1 != node2) {
                    node1.createRelationshipTo(node2, knows).setProperty("weight",random);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        tx.success();
    }
    System.out.println("generated rel-count = " + count+" time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-now)+" ms");

    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String uuidString = "flw-"+ now;
    count=0;
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        for (Relationship r : GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllRelationships()) {
            if (r.hasProperty("weight"))
                r.setProperty(uuidString, r.getProperty("weight"));
            count++;
        }
        tx.success();
    }
    System.out.println("global graph ops rel-count = " + count+" time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-now)+" ms");

    final AtomicInteger pathLenght=new AtomicInteger();
    final AtomicInteger pathCount=new AtomicInteger();
    TraversalDescription tempTraversal  = db.traversalDescription()
            .depthFirst()
            .uniqueness(new UniquenessFactory() {
                            @Override
                            public UniquenessFilter create(Object optionalParameter) {
                                return new UniquenessFilter() {
                                    Set<Relationship> rels = new HashSet<Relationship>(100000);
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean checkFirst(TraversalBranch branch) {
                                        pathCount.incrementAndGet();
                                        pathLenght.set(Math.max(pathLenght.get(),branch.length()));
                                        return rels.add(branch.lastRelationship());
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public boolean check(TraversalBranch branch) {
                                        pathCount.incrementAndGet();
                                        pathLenght.set(Math.max(pathLenght.get(),branch.length()));
                                        return rels.add(branch.lastRelationship());
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        }
     );
    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
    count=0;
    try {
        for(Relationship r : tempTraversal.traverse(nodes.get(0))
                .relationships()){
            if (r.hasProperty("weight"))
                r.setProperty(uuidString,r.getProperty("weight"));
            count++;
        }
        tx.success();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("assingTempProperty: " + e);
        tx.failure();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }
    System.out.println("rel-count = " + count+" time "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-now)+" ms pathlength "+pathLenght.get()+" pathCount "+pathCount.get());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with this snippet I've learned many things. The problem was that someone was launching Threads (Don't know why) just before this method and was causing a mess.